# Mooc Helsinki Part 1 Week 4 Exercise 18 Java Weird Occurrence

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, oop, java.util.scanner

Having a problem here with this error which the solution to is simply beyond me.

FAIL: PersonalInformationCollectionTest testInputFirst
Something weird occurred. It could be that the void main (String[] args) method of the class class PersonalInformationCollection has disappeared or your program crashed due to an exception. More information: java.util.NoSuchElementException.

It then says the same thing but for testInputSecond as well.

Can't find any reason for whats wrong. Looked online at a correct solution and perhaps it's just my poor eye sight but i couldn't see a single difference between my somehow incorrect code and their correct code.

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PersonalInformationCollection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // implement here your program that uses the PersonalInformation class

        ArrayList<PersonalInformation> infoCollection = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("First name: ");
            String firstName = scanner.next();

            if (firstName.isEmpty()){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Last name: ");
            String lastName = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Identification number: ");
            String idNumber = scanner.next();
            infoCollection.add(new PersonalInformation(firstName, lastName, idNumber));
        }
        for (PersonalInformation personalInfo : infoCollection){
            System.out.println(personalInfo.getFirstName() + " " +  personalInfo.getLastName());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The real error starts with `java.util.NoSuchElementException` - *probable* cause: there is nothing more to read from standard input while calling `scanner.next()` - I can't see the input, but maybe you should use `scanner.hasNext()` to test if there is still input that can be read (BTW the start of that error message is **not** standard Java, more like someone being funny)

Comment: Perhaps they are sending EOF instead of a newline for the empty string. Try that locally. (i.e. type a CTRL-D on linux or CTRL-Z on Windows)

Comment: Terrible title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using scanner.nextLine() rather than scanner.next(). No idea how that made such a difference in this case

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the more general type for your variables as you can, because it doesn't change the logic if you would use an LinkedList instaed of an Arraylist and also it has the same methods you are using.
2. For strings use scanner,nextLine()
3. numberId or simply id should be a number integer would be great so use scanner.nextInt() to get only integer in here
4. implement/override the toString methode in your class PersonalInformation to have the string reprensetation at one point

class PersonalInformation

```
public class PersonalInformation {

    private final int id;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    public PersonalInformation(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    private int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PersonalInformation{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

class PersonalInformationCollection

```
public static class PersonalInformationCollection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // implement here your program that uses the PersonalInformation class

        List<PersonalInformation> infoCollection = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Identification number: ");
            int id = scanner.nextInt();

            if (id < 0){
                break;
            }

            System.out.print("First name: ");
            String firstName = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Last name: ");
            String lastName = scanner.next();
            infoCollection.add(new PersonalInformation(id, firstName, lastName));
        }

        for (PersonalInformation personalInfo : infoCollection){
            System.out.println(personalInfo);
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```